# Jquery hover efect in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of projects with images that have hover effect. Hover effect shows project description. I made a loop that shows for 3 seconds every project description.

The problem is when you mouse enter some element it shows text, but when loop catches it hides project text. And you need leave and enter the element to show text again. I want to prevent from text to hide if element is already hovered.

```
    var index = 0;
    var duration = 3000;
    function loopProjects() {
        $('.port-hov').each(function(index,item) {

            index = index + 1;
            //console.log(index);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(item).mouseenter();},duration);

            duration = duration + 3000;

            setTimeout(function(){
                $(item).mouseleave();},duration);
        });
    }


    setInterval(loopProjects, index * 4000);
```

Solution!

```
    function loopProjects() {
        $('.port-hov').each(function(index,item) {
            index = index + 1;
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(item).mouseenter();},duration);

            duration = duration + 3000;

            setTimeout(function(){
                if (!$(item).is(":hover")){
                    $(item).mouseleave();}},duration);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Before calling `mouseleave`, test if `item` is under the mouse. `if (!$(item).is(":hover"))`

Comment: I already did that. But on wrong place :) Thanks for opening my eyes :D